# I am participating in my first hackathon and I have a doubt regarding public and private leaderboard

Tags: overfitting, roc

In the competition that I am participating 40 percentage of the data is taken for public leaderboard and 60 percentage is reserved for private leaderboard.

**Question 1**

On public leaderboard I'm getting a roc_auc score of 0.86. how do I know if I am not overfitting to the public leaderboard?

**Question 2**

My problem statement is a binary classification problem.so I want to know if the test data on which we have to make the prediction will contain the same percentage of positive samples as train dataset??

I am new to posting questions on stackexchange so please bear with my mistakes

Comment: Regarding question 2—that's up to the organizers of your contest. The test data can be whatever they want. Either they've posted information about the distribution somewhere, or they don't intend for you to know it _a priori_, and your model must handle that uncertainty.

Comment: Regarding question 1—a worthwhile way to check is to hold out a 'test set' of your own from the training data you're given. See whether your performance on that is comparable to on the public test set.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The dataset provided to me has 2,52,000 observations. So I used. 80/20 split for training and validation.got training ROC score of 0.91 and validation ROC score of 0.89